# flutter, what is the right way to change appbar leading icon at app theme level?

Tags: flutter, flutter-theme

flutter,  what is the right way to change appbar leading icon at app theme level? so I no need to change on each screen?

I know the following code work for specific screen...

```
AppBar(
  title: Text("Hello Appbar"),
  leading: Icon(
    Icons.arrow_back,
  ),
);
```

but I don't want to do it on each screen, Just checking here if I can set it at app theme level so it is same for all screen...

I referred flutter documentation for [appbar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBarTheme-class.html), but it was not much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

AppBar MyAppBar({Widget title, Widget leading}) {
  return AppBar(
    title: title,
    leading: leading,
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use IconButton to change the leading icon.

```
 AppBar(
  title: Text("Hello Appbar"),
  leading: IconButton(
   onPressed: () {},
   icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back)
  ),
);
```